# Ads working in iOS build but not working at all in Android build

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, android-build, unityads

I am facing a issue with unity ads from last week. Ads are working fine in Unity editor. In iOS build ads are working fine, but in Android build ads are not working at all. I am using built in ads and using unity 2017.2.

Tried every thing that is on internet for solving this problem. Reinstalled unity, switched to latest version, deleted connection settings from package and tried various conventions to code unity ads but problem never solved. In android build ads are not even show in test mode.

Bellow is the example of code that I have implemented to show ads when game fail. Same code works fine in iOS build but not in android. I have tested on 4 different android devices so it is not the problem with device and I have enough fast internet connection for ads to show.

Two projects I have recently created are having this problem and one old project that was showing ads and I made new buid to update this project and it also started to not show any ad. My other old projects working fine and showing android ads, but from last week any new android build not showing ads.

```
public void LevelFailed()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowAds());
}

IEnumerator ShowAds()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
        yield break;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    { 
        Advertisement.Show();
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally ads are working. Problem was with unity 2017.2 all updates. After installing Unity 2017.3.0f3 ads stated to work just fine in the android build.